# Link row in one SQL table to multiple rows in different table,

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm making a web based tool to parse URLs. It works with two tables. One for the URLs, and one for the words found and their parses/number of occurrences. Here is a simplified example:

```
URLs

url-id      url
----------------------------------------------------
1           www.example.net/this-is-a-sentence
2           www.example.org/this-is-another-sentence


Words

word-id  word         category        occurences
----------------------------------------------------
1        this         pronoun         2
2        is           verb            2
3        a            det             1
4        sentence     noun            2
5        another      det             1
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to link each URL in the URL table to each of its words in the Words table. This way, if a user decides to delete one of the URLs, all the appropriate occurrence counts can be decremented. I'm totally new to SQL so I have no clue how it's capable of storing information in cells, but I want to have some kind of dynamically sized list of all the word-ids in a URL.

```
url-id      url                                         words
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           www.example.net/this-is-a-sentence          1,2,3,4
2           www.example.org/this-is-another-sentence    1,2,3,5
```

I am open to suggestions of entirely different ways to organize the data within SQL.

Note - I can't simply parse the URLs again when deleting, because there is user input required to verify the parse when multiple are possible.

Comment: You would need to use another table and insert rows with the url_id and word_id

Comment: Add `url_id` to your `Words` table as foreign key?

Comment: @ChipDean - So a kind of "linking table"?

Comment: @Samurai - If I'm understanding you, that's sort of the same problem in reverse: the same word could occur in hundreds of URLs, and you'd need to store IDs for all of them.

Comment: The linking table would have 2 columns, `FK_url-id` and `FK_word-id` ... Then, if you wanted`url-id` 1 to have `word-id` 1,2,3 and 4 linked, then the linking table would have 4 rows inserted (`1,1`,`1,2`,`1,3`,`1,4`) ... See what I did there? ...

Comment: Ah right, having a third table with all `word_id`s and `url_id`s will do fine then. Alternatively you can add a column to `Words` to keep all the corresponding `url_id`s like comma separated then. If URL deleted then you search that colum in Words that contains that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bridging table like this:

```
url-id      word-id     (represents, not part of table)
-------------------
1           1           url-id 1 has word-id 1 (this)
1           2           url-id 1 has word-id 2 (is)       
1           3           url-id 1 has word-id 3 (a)
1           4           url-id 1 has word-id 4 (sentence)
2           1           url-id 2 has word-id 1 (this)
2           2           url-id 2 has word-id 2 (is)
2           5           url-id 2 has word-id 5 (another)
2           4           url-id 2 has word-id 4 (sentence)
```

This is called a Many to Many relationship. A URL can have many Words and a Word can belong to many URL's. [Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) is a good article describing different relationships in SQL.